# Stop Calculator refreshing page on submit

Tags: javascript, php, calculator

How would I go about preventing the page from refreshing when pressing the "Calculate" button on this BRM caculator?

The validation is setup working fine, but then the page is  refreshed.

Currently, users who click "Calculate!", Are thrown back to the top of the page and have to scroll down again to find out the answer.

Unfortunately, my knowledge of JS and PHP is basic.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL&(~E_NOTICE));
session_start();

# set this to 0 if you want to calculate only BMR and to 1 if you want 
# to calculate BMR + daily energy requirements
$calc_mode=1;
?>
<style type="text/css">
.calculator_div
{
    font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    border:2pt solid #4444FF;
    padding:5px;
    width:330px;
    margin:auto;
}

label
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:150px;        
}
.label
{
    display:inline;
    float:none;
    width:75px;     
    font-size:11px
}
.warning
{
    background:yellow;
    border:1pt solid red;
    padding:5px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

 #table{

    width:100%;

    }

  #row  {
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
    }
.rowheader  
{
    padding:5px;    
    font-size:14px; 
    font-weight:bolder;         
    color:white;    
    text-align:center;
}  
</style>
<script language="javascript"> 
function IsNumber(fldId)
{
  var fld=document.getElementById(fldId).value;

  if(isNaN(fld))
  {     
        document.getElementById(fldId).value=fld.substring(0, fld.length-1);
        var newvalue=document.getElementById(fldId).value;
        IsNumber(fldId);
  }

  return;   
}


function FtToCm(ftfld,infld,savefld)
{
    var ft=document.getElementById(ftfld).value;
    var inch=document.getElementById(infld).value;

    if(!isNaN(ft) && !isNaN(inch))
    {
        var allinch= ft * 12;
        allinch= parseInt(allinch) + parseInt(inch);

        var cm =allinch * 2.54;

        document.getElementById(savefld).value=Math.round(cm);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("feet").value=ft.substring(0, ft.length-1);
        document.getElementById("inch").value=inch.substring(0, inch.length-1);
    }
    //form2.field.value =lbs;
    //alert(field);
    return;
}

function CmToFt(cm,ftfld,infld)
{
    if(!isNaN(cm))
    {
        var newcm=cm * 0.3937;

        var ft = newcm / 12;
        var remain= newcm % 12;
        var inchs= remain;

        document.getElementById(ftfld).value=Math.round(ft);
        document.getElementById(infld).value=Math.round(inchs);
    }
    else
    {    
        document.getElementById("cm").value=cm.substring(0, cm.length-1);
    }
    //form2.field.value =lbs;
    //alert(field);
    return;
}

function KgToLbs(kg,field)
{
    if(!isNaN(kg))
    {
        var lbs= kg * 2.2;    
        document.getElementById(field).value=Math.round(lbs);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("kg").value=kg.substring(0, kg.length-1);
    }
    //form2.field.value =lbs;
    //alert(field);
    return;
}

function LbsToKg(lbs,field)
{
    if(!isNaN(lbs))
    {
        var kg= lbs / 2.2;
        document.getElementById(field).value=Math.round(kg);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("lbs").value=lbs.substring(0, lbs.length-1);
    }
    return;
}
function validateForm(frm)
{

    age=frm.age.value;
    kg=frm.kg.value;
    cm=frm.cm.value;

    if(age=="" || kg=="" || cm=="" )
    {
        alert('Error: all fields are required!');
        return false;
    }

    return;
}

function showHide(fldshow,fldhide,label,labelfld) 
{
    var myTextelemShow = document.getElementById(fldshow);
    var myTextelemLabel = document.getElementById(labelfld);
    var myTextelemHide = document.getElementById(fldhide);
    if(myTextelemShow.style.display == 'none')
    {
        myTextelemShow.style.display = 'inline' ;
        myTextelemLabel.innerHTML = label;
    }
    if(myTextelemHide.style.display != 'none')
    {
        myTextelemHide.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['calculator_ok']))
{
    // session storage
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$var) $_SESSION["calc_bmr_".$key]=$var;

    $inch=$_POST["feet"]*12+$_POST["inch"]; 

    if($_POST["gender"]=='male')
    {
        $BMR=66 + (6.3 * $_POST["lbs"]) + (12.9 * $inch) - (6.8 * $_POST["age"]);           
    }
    else
    {
        $BMR=655 + (4.3 * $_POST["lbs"]) + (4.7 * $inch) - (4.7 * $_POST["age"]);
    }

    // activity?
    if($calc_mode)
    {
        $extra_energy=$BMR*$_POST["activity"];
        $energy_needs=round($BMR+$extra_energy);
    }
}
?>

<div class="calculator_div">
    <form method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
    <p><label>Your age:</label>
                    <input type="text" size="7"  name="age" id="age" onkeyup="IsNumber(this.id)" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["calc_bmr_age"];?>" > 
    </p>
    <p><label>Gender:</label>
                    <input id="gender"  name="gender" type="radio" value="male" <?php if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_gender"]=="male") echo "checked"; else { if(!isset($_SESSION["calc_bmr_gender"])) echo "checked";}?> /> <label style="width:75px;display:inline;float:none;">Male</label>
                    <input id="gender"  name="gender" type="radio" value="female" <?php if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_gender"]=="female") echo "checked"; ?>/> <label style="width:75px;display:inline;float:none;">Female</label>

    </p>
    <p><label>Your weight:</label>
                    <input id="weight" name="weight" type="radio" value="lbs" onclick="showHide('lbs','kg','Lbs','labelw');" <?php if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_weight"]=="lbs") echo "checked"; else { if(!isset($_SESSION["calc_bmr_weight"])) echo "checked";}?> />
                    <label style="width:75px;display:inline;float:none;">lbs</label>
                    <input id="weight"  name="weight" type="radio" value="kg" onclick="showHide('kg','lbs','kg','labelw');" <? if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_weight"]=="kg") echo "checked"; ?> />
                    <label style="width:75px;display:inline;float:none;">kg</label>

    </p>
        <p><label >&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lbs" id="lbs" size="4" onkeyup="LbsToKg(this.value,'kg');" value="<? echo $_SESSION["calc_bmr_lbs"];?>">  
                    <input type="text" name="kg" id="kg" size="4" onkeyup="KgToLbs(this.value,'lbs');" style="display:none;" value="<? echo $_SESSION["calc_bmr_kg"]; ?>"> 

                    <span id="labelw">
                    <?php if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_weight"]=="kg"):?>
                            kg
                            <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
                            showHide('kg','lbs','kg','labelw'); 
                            </SCRIPT>
                    <?php else:?>lbs<?php endif;?>
                    </span>
    </p>


    <p><label>Your height:</label>
                    <input id="height"  name="height" type="radio" value="cm" onclick="showHide('cm','feet','CM','labelh');showHide('cm','inch','CM','labelh');" <? if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_height"]=="cm") echo "checked"; else { if(!isset($_SESSION["calc_bmr_heigth"])) echo "checked";}?> />
                    <label style="width:75px;display:inline;float:none;">cm</label>
                    <input id="height" name="height" type="radio" value="feet" onclick="showHide('feet','cm','feet/inch','labelh');showHide('inch','cm','feet/inch','labelh');" <? if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_height"]=="feet") echo "checked"; ?> />
                    <label style="width:75px;display:inline;float:none;">feet/inch</label>

    </p>
        <p><label >&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cm" id="cm" size="4" onkeyup="IsNumber(this.id);CmToFt(this.value,'feet','inch');" value="<? echo $_SESSION["calc_bmr_cm"];?>">  
                    <input type="text" name="feet" id="feet" size="4" onkeyup="IsNumber(this.id);FtToCm('feet','inch','cm');" style="display:none;" value="<? echo $_SESSION["calc_bmr_feet"]; ?>"> 
                    <input type="text" name="inch" id="inch" size="4" onkeyup="IsNumber(this.id);FtToCm('feet','inch','cm');" style="display:none;" value="<? echo $_SESSION["calc_bmr_inch"]; ?>"> 
                    <span id=labelh > 
                    <?php if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_height"]=="feet"):?>
                    feet/inch
                    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
                    showHide('feet','cm','feet/inch','labelh');
                    showHide('inch','cm','feet/inch','labelh'); 
                    </SCRIPT>
                    <?php else:?>cm<?php endif;?>
                   </span>
    </p>

    <?php if($calc_mode==1):?>
        <p><label>Daily Activity:</label> <select name="activity">    
        <option value="0.2" <?if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_activity"]=="0.2") echo "selected"?>>No sport/exercise</option>
        <option value="0.375" <?if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_activity"]=="0.375") echo "selected"?>>Light activity (sport 1-3 times per week)</option>
        <option value="0.55" <?if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_activity"]=="0.55") echo "selected"?>>Moderate activity (sport 3-5 times per week)</option>
        <option value="0.725" <?if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_activity"]=="0.725") echo "selected"?>>High activity (everyday exercise)</option>
        <option value="0.9" <?if($_SESSION["calc_bmr_activity"]=="0.9") echo "selected"?>>Extreme activity (professional athlete)</option>  
        </select></p>
    <?php endif;?>

    <div style="text-align:center;clear:both;"><input type="submit" value="Calculate!"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="calculator_ok" value="1">
    </form> 


<?php if(!empty($_POST['calculator_ok'])):?>
    <div id="table">
        <div class="rowheader" style="background-color:#4BACE6;">
                        Your BMR is: <?echo number_format($BMR); ?> calories/day
        </div>
        <?php if($calc_mode):?>
        <div class="rowheader" style="background-color:#4BACE6;">
            <p>You need <?php echo number_format($energy_needs)?> calories per day.</p>
        </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
    <p align="center"><a href="http://calendarscripts.info/overweight-calculator.html" style="font-size:10px;">Are you overweight?</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `return false;` into validateForm() should stop form submission.

But since you're calculating on server side and everything is in the same file, it'll not work anyway.

So, first, you should move the calculation part to a separated PHP file:

**calculate.php**

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['calculator_ok']))
{
    // session storage
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$var) $_SESSION["calc_bmr_".$key]=$var;

    $inch=$_POST["feet"]*12+$_POST["inch"]; 

    if($_POST["gender"]=='male')
    {
        $BMR=66 + (6.3 * $_POST["lbs"]) + (12.9 * $inch) - (6.8 * $_POST["age"]);           
    }
    else
    {
        $BMR=655 + (4.3 * $_POST["lbs"]) + (4.7 * $inch) - (4.7 * $_POST["age"]);
    }

    // activity?
    if($calc_mode)
    {
        $extra_energy=$BMR*$_POST["activity"];
        $energy_needs=round($BMR+$extra_energy);
    }

    $result = [
        'bmr' => $BMR,
        'energy_needs' => $energy_needs
    ];

    // Outputs $result as a JSON object
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Then, adjust the validateForm() method to call **calculate.php** via AJAX:

```
function validateForm(frm) {

    // Hide results
    $('#table').hide();

    // Do the validation code here

    $.ajax({
        url: 'calculate.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $(frm).serialize()
    }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       $('#table').show();
       $('#bmr').html(data.bmr);
       $('#energy_needs').html(data.energy_needs);
    });

    return false; // Prevent form submission

}
```

Finally, you should adjust the code that shows the results. Once we've moved the calculation to AJAX, the page won't refresh anymore. For this reason, you should update this information using JavaScript:

```
<div id="table">
    <div class="rowheader" style="background-color:#4BACE6;">
         Your BMR is: <span id="bmr"></span> calories/day
    </div>
    <?php if($calc_mode):?>
    <div class="rowheader" style="background-color:#4BACE6;">
        <p>You need <span id="energy_needs"></span> calories per day.</p>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after I moved the calculation part from the initial file to a separated calculate.php file and upload it, I need to replace two sections in the remaining code?

Replace this:

```
function validateForm(frm)
{

    age=frm.age.value;
    kg=frm.kg.value;
    cm=frm.cm.value;

    if(age=="" || kg=="" || cm=="" )
    {
        alert('Error: all fields are required!');
        return false;
    }

    return;
}
```

In this:

```
function validateForm(frm) {

    // Hide results
    $('#table').hide();

    // Do the validation code here

    $.ajax({
        url: 'calculate.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $(frm).serialize()
    }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       $('#table').show();
       $('#bmr').html(data.bmr);
       $('#energy_needs').html(data.energy_needs);
    });

    return false; // Prevent form submission

}
```

And this sction:

```
<div id="table">
        <div class="rowheader" style="background-color:#4BACE6;">
                        Your BMR is: <?echo number_format($BMR); ?> calories/day
        </div>
        <?php if($calc_mode):?>
        <div class="rowheader" style="background-color:#4BACE6;">
            <p>You need <?php echo number_format($energy_needs)?> calories per day.</p>
        </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
    <p align="center"><a href="http://calendarscripts.info/overweight-calculator.html" style="font-size:10px;">Are you overweight?</a></p>
</div>
```

With this:

```
<div id="table">
    <div class="rowheader" style="background-color:#4BACE6;">
         Your BMR is: <span id="bmr"></span> calories/day
    </div>
    <?php if($calc_mode):?>
    <div class="rowheader" style="background-color:#4BACE6;">
        <p>You need <span id="energy_needs"></span> calories per day.</p>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Everything else stays the same?

And this is the only code that goes into the separate calculate.php:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['calculator_ok']))
{
    // session storage
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$var) $_SESSION["calc_bmr_".$key]=$var;

    $inch=$_POST["feet"]*12+$_POST["inch"]; 

    if($_POST["gender"]=='male')
    {
        $BMR=66 + (6.3 * $_POST["lbs"]) + (12.9 * $inch) - (6.8 * $_POST["age"]);           
    }
    else
    {
        $BMR=655 + (4.3 * $_POST["lbs"]) + (4.7 * $inch) - (4.7 * $_POST["age"]);
    }

    // activity?
    if($calc_mode)
    {
        $extra_energy=$BMR*$_POST["activity"];
        $energy_needs=round($BMR+$extra_energy);
    }

    $result = [
        'bmr' => $BMR,
        'energy_needs' => $energy_needs
    ];

    // Outputs $result as a JSON object
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Don't I need to end it with:

```
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: anyone have an answer?